# Using Parse4J with LibGDX?

Tags: java, parse-platform, libgdx, parse4j

Is there a way of using the [Parse4J](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/parse4j) libary with LibGDX?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it in the desktop module of your project. Keep in mind that it is no official SDK and might miss some of the features that Parse.com provides!

For the Android / iOS modules, I would not recommend using it, since there are official SDKs for those platforms: https://parse.com/docs/downloads